# How to disable view page source in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, autohotkey, javascript

I need one help from you that is to block the page of viewing the source (original sites should be opened but source page must be blocked).

I have almost come to the solution with the help of AutoHotKey by blocking the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> but not able to block the “right click > view page source” option for the websites (exp:- www.google.com) where I can not disable the right click as per business requirement.

I have almost 8,000 to 9,000 users in domain environment. Trying to find out such solution (script) through which it can be achieved. The users in my environment do not have the admin level access.

Can anybody please help me to block this option? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be you can't. One can easily view the main HTML page only by downloading that page. Or type `view-source` before URL.

Comment: I have already restricted those two options but looking for the solution right click>>View page source" to be blocked. I am stuck there only.

Comment: this is basically the business requirement to not to access end users of client web page source because they can take the source code and use unethically. That is why we must have to restrict them to access or view the source code.

Comment: I believe I understand, but can you clarify what you’re asking for: (1) A way to gimmick a web page so its source can’t be viewed, or (2) A way to configure workstations *where you have administrator access* so the users (who do *not* have administrator access) cannot do (Right click) → “View Page Source” in Chrome.  If it’s #2, is the website on a secure intranet?  Because, if it’s on the Internet, what’s to stop users from accessing it from other machines?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AutoHotkey already, write a loop that starts out waiting indefinitely for the active window title to change (`WinWaitNotActive % "ahk_id" WinExist("A")`).

For the remaining part of the loop that executes each time the window title changes, check for the URL or window of interest (`If Instr(WinExist("A"), "view-source:")`), and then close the window (or presumably the browser tab) once it opens using `WinClose` or `SendInput, ^F4` or similar.

Comment: They can still save the source (CTRL + S) and open it with a text editor like Notepad...